# How to correctly set diacritic insensitive $text index for spanish lang

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search, diacritics

I’m struggling to find out how to correctly set a diacritic insensitive text index for my collection of persons. It’s a normal collection without collation.

The MongoDB version is 5.0.15

I need a text index (not using mongo atlas) for the name and familyName fields. I created an index with this config:

```json
{
  "v": 2,
  "key": {
    "_fts": "text",
    "_ftsx": 1
  },
  "name": "personsFullname",
  "weights": {
    "familyName": 1,
    "name": 1
  },
  "default_language": "es",
  "language_override": "language",
  "textIndexVersion": 3
}
```

The problem is that even though the MongoDB manual says that from version 3 the text search is diacritic insensitive it doesn’t work that way. Or at least I'm not sure if the version refers to the prop `"v": 2`, or `"textIndexVersion": 3`.

Suppose I have these 3 records:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "aaaaaaa",
    "name": "Roberto ",
    "familyName": "Torres García "
  },
  {
    "_id": "bbbbbbb",
    "name": "Ruben A",
    "familyName": "Parras García"
  },
  {
    _id:"ccccc",
    "name": "Karla",
    "familyName": "Rosas García"
  }
]
```

If I search for `García` (using diacritic for i):

```
db.getCollection("personsData").find({ "$text": { "$search": "García" } })
```

It finds the 3 records.

But if I search for `Garcia` (Not using diacritic for i):

```
db.getCollection("personsData").find({ "$text": { "$search": "Garcia" } })
```

It finds no records.

What am I missing here?

Any help or hint is pretty much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are `"_fts"` and `"_ftsx"`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have no idea. Those were generated when I created the index.

Comment: How was the index created?

Comment: Using Studio 3T Free Edition

Comment: I wonder if this is diacritic bug related to `"default_language": "es"`.  For example, not using `"default_language": "es"`, i.e. defaulting to English, [diacritic insensitivity seems to work](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nWQp_fsAEoH "link to mongoplayground.net example -->").  In the linked mongoplayground.net example, you comment/uncomment the various lines to see the effect.

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna check it out later and report back. :)

Comment: It works with English a default lang. I tested it in the playground and in my instance. The big question is why it doesn't work for Spanish.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know why it is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

Following  @rickhg12hs advice:

- If I test locally, on mongo version 6.0.5 works, if I don't set *default_language: "spanish"*

```js
db.consultas.createIndex(
  { diagnostico: "text" },
);
```

On the online *mongoPlayground*, as @rickhg12hs points out,  works in that way:

The playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/P6TVAR8T1oU

And if you want to reproduce the example in a local instance (I'm using docker 6.0.5):

```js
use("clinica");

db.consultas.insertMany([
  {
    nombre: "Juan Perez",
    especialidad: "general",
    diagnostico: "Dolor abdominal, Fiebre alta, tos, posible caso de COVID",
  },
  {
    nombre: "María Pelaez",
    especialidad: "general",
    diagnostico: "Tensión alta, posible episodio de ataque de ansiedad",
  },
  {
    nombre: "Javier Garcia",
    especialidad: "cardiología",
    diagnostico: "Arritmias, acompañado de tensión alta, enfermería",
  },
  {
    nombre: "Manuel Gómez",
    especialidad: "general",
    diagnostico: "Fiebre alta, tos y mucosidades, enfermería",
  },
]);
```

Creating the index

```js
db.consultas.createIndex(
  { diagnostico: "text" },
);
```

And launching the query (you can try both options *enfermería* and *enfermeria* you get results

```js
db.consultas.find({ $text: { $search: "enfermeria" } });
```

I didn't need to go for the ellaborated version

I read on other posts to try

**THIS SEEMS NOT TO BE NEEDED ON VERSION 6**

```js
db.consultas.createIndex(
  { diagnostico: "text" },
  {
    defaultLanguage: "es",
    textIndexVersion: 3,
  }
);
```

And in the query indicate to ignore diacritics:

```js
db.consultas.find({
  $text: {
    $search: "enfermeria",
    $diacriticSensitive: false,
  },
});
```